# How to find local maximums in data set using C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I am using an arduino to read a sensor which stores 256 values into an array. I am trying to find local max's but some values being stored have repeating values to the left and right of itself causing the value to print multiple times. Is there a way to take all true values meaning they are a max value and store them in another array to process and reduce the repeated values to just 1 value...

OR is there a way to send the max values to another array where the repeated values get reduced to just 1? OR 
IE:

```
Array1[] = {1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,7,8,9,10}

max = 4 at index 3
max = 4 at index 4
max = 4 at index 5
```

since 4 is a peak point but repeats how can I reduce it so that the array looks like

```
Array2[] = {1,2,3,4,3,2,7,8,9,10}

max = 4 at index 3
```

I need the most basic breakdown if possible nothing on an expert level, thanks.

Code from Arduino:

```
int inp[20] = {24,100,13,155,154,157,156,140,14,175,158,102,169,160,190,100,200,164,143,20};
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  // for debugging  
}

void loop()
{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
       Serial.println((String)inp[i]+" index at - "+i);
       delay(100);
    };   

 int N = 5;   // loc max neighborhood size
 for (int i = N-1; i < 19-N; i++) 
  {
      bool loc = false;
      for (int j = 1; j < N; j++) // look N-1 back and N-1 ahead
      { 
        if (inp[i] > inp[i-j] && inp[i] > inp[i+j]) loc = true;
      }
        if (loc == true)
        {         
          Serial.println((String)"max = "inp[i]+" at index "+i);
        }
     }
  Serial.println("----------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: You 're searching for peaks, not max. A set of data may contain more than one peaks. That means you can't just remove duplicates from a set of data. However, there is no need to print duplicate values. So, every time you find a peak, store it. Then if you ever encounter the same peak just ignore it (don't print it).

Comment: How may I go about storing it?

Comment: Data range is [0 255] (256 values). So, make another array of size 256, init all elements to 0 and then everytime you a peak increase the array at the appropriate position. That way, every time you get a peak you just check the array if it's 0 at this position. If yes, print the peak if not, ignore it.

Comment: Are you describing the problem correctly? Doesn't your posted code print "max 154 at 4", "max 157 at 5", "max 156 at 6"? IOW doesn't it just print the values around local maximum regardless if those are equal with maximum or not?

Comment: How is it relevant to your algorithm where the data came from, like an Arduino? Please extract a [mcve] and also be specific with the problem you have. In particular don't just dump your intepretation but provide the actual observations instead. That said, format your code consistently if you want anyone to read it.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect "local maxima" or peaks in a single loop without the need of  copying something into another array. You just have to ignore repeating values, and you just have to keep track if the values considered are currently increasing or decreasing. Each value after which this status switches from increasing to decreasing is then a peak:

```
int main() {

    int Array1[] = {1,2,3,4,4,4,3,2,7,8,9,10};

    int prevVal = INT_MIN;
    enum {
        Ascending,
        Descending
    } direction = Ascending;

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(Array1)/sizeof(*Array1); i++) {
        int curVal = Array1[i];
        if (prevVal < curVal) {  // (still) ascending?
            direction = Ascending;
        }
        else if (prevVal > curVal) { // (still) descending?
            if (direction != Descending) { // starts descending?
                cout << "peak at index " << i-1 << ": " << prevVal << endl;
                direction = Descending;
            }
        }
        // prevVal == curVal is simply ignored...

        prevVal = curVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: hopefully. Maybe you have to adapt the syntax, but the approach itself should work in any procedural language.